# adding maven project to non maven project

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have a non-maven project and I have another maven project that writes tests for the non maven project. I have copied the maven project into the directory of the non maven project but noticed that the project is no longer labelled as a maven project. how do I add maven support for the test directory again? I am using intellij for the project.

[attached is my projects directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUH3n.png)

Comment: Please explain exactly what your directory structure is. I'd suggest that you use the same build tool for both.

Comment: What happens if you right-click on your pom.xml and choose "Add as Maven project"?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do it in the following way:

- Close the IDE and remove all `.idea` folders and `.iml` files from your project via the OS file manager
- Move the Maven project from non-Maven one
- In IntelliJ IDEA, click on `File | New | Project... | Empty Project`
- Go to `File | Project Structure | Modules` and import your project as modules one by one